# Cloth object isn't hanging from pin group

Tags: cloth-simulation, vertex-groups

I added cloth physic to the object "net". But it is not hanging from the pin group I selected.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KqY6acL7cBDJX16X0XAzXgWaHh-AMCuZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch to *Weight Paint* mode you'll see that the weight is very low for your pin group, so go into *Object Data > Vertex Group*, select the group, make sure that the *Weight* value is at 1 (it is already the case) and click on the *Assign* button:

[image]